# How to empty Woocommerce cart after a period of time?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to automatically empty complete Woocommerce cart from products after 5 minutes. Is there a way to programmatically do so?

Answer (score 0):

First set a Session or cookie with current time on `woocommerce_add_to_cart` hook.

Once page load, You can check with `init` hook if difference between current time and session time is more then 300 second then you can clear cart.

```
global $woocommerce;
$woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
```